# How to store an int array in a mysql db?

Tags: c++, mysql

I want this array intact and I don't need to access each element individually just as a whole.

I have tried storing my int array as a char array and pushing it into a varchar of size 512

```
 char temp[512];
 memcpy(temp, arr, sizeof(temp));
 sprintf(insert, "insert into SiftFeatures(M_Id, FeatureData) values((Select M_Id from Master where M_Id='1'), '%s' )" , temp);
if(mysql_query(con, insert)){
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
}
```

But the data doesn't store correctly.

Then I thought of trying a blob data structure as a column field in my sql db and am having issues with that.

Comment: What's the data type of the column receiving the serialized array? What the data   doesn't store correctly? What do you expect and what's happening?

Comment: Check out the MySql Connector C++ overloads of the `istream` and `ostream` methods in the BLOB functions.  Be aware that the multibyte integer formats much match the target platform (a.k.a. Endianess).

Comment: @Thomas Mathews. Right I thought about the Endianness but the bytes just don't make sense. They are not putting in the right bits at all.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda. As I mentioned, I tried to store it as a varchar(512) as my column type. I expect the corresponding chars for those bytes to be stored. So if I have  0110 1111 I expect to see a "A" because that byte = 101 and in ascii thats the letter "A"

Comment: I assume it might have something to do with my sprintf statement mixed with my "mysql_query" not getting passed in as I expect.

Comment: sorry "e" in the comment above.